# WebRTC Native API for Android

Tags: android, webrtc

I want to develop Android Native video chat  app using WebRTC(Not browser).
 Main feature is Android user can able to call  Desktop web browser.
Any way?(please without third party API)

Comment: https://github.com/pristineio/webrtc-build-scripts has an android project that can be easily imported (I'm using IntelliJ) and a native android app compiled in minutes.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible using javascript (intel xdk) hybrid app

link:https://crosswalk-project.org/