# Android HTTP Streaming

Tags: android, android-camera

Basically what I want to do is setup an Android program that shows a camera preview and sends the preview frame by frame to a server. I have code setup that will handle sending to the server. I just need a way to setup a camera preview and grab each frame one by one. Any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: There's no way I can see this working without absolutely bogging down the native application. Sending a picture to a server once you take it takes 5-6 seconds on WIFI, I don't see how you could possibly do this frame by frame without entering your app into gridlock :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21473294/webrtc-native-api-for-android. Diff protocol but still wort looking into

Comment: Then how is that ip camera apps work so well? If they manage to do it, shouldn't it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the requirement ? i think sending each frame would really really eat away battery...

Instead what i can figure out is this...

1. create 2 videoview one for recording in preview mode and one for user explicit recording.
2. as soon as the user enters the preview mode you will actually record the video but will   show to user as preview.
3. once the user clicks on recording then you will stop the preview video and send it to server in the background using AsycnTask and start recording the user explicit video.
4. what if the user does not records and leaves the activity? you can use `onpause()` life cycle of the activity where you will upload the video to server.
5. in the `ondestroy()` or after uploading you can always delete the file.

The plain benefit is you will only use one file upload with too much ease.

1. On the server if you want to get images from video you can use tools like ffmpeg which can easily split video into its frame ( but i guess ffmpeg dont usually comes in shared hosting ... temporarily you can work on localhost and see all the functionalities what i usually do :) )

If its live chatting sort of thing then i need to rethink....

This is all what i can guess :)

Thanks and hope it helps you...

Comment: The idea behind the project is that an object (from a specific set of possible objects, think machine parts) is to be held in view of the android device. The android device then continuously sends images of the object to a server. The server will then continuously analyze the data and send back information(rectangle coordinates) that will then edit the display by showing the rectangle on top of the view. 
So I guess ultimately it's closer to a livechatting app.